# Target location type 'Profile' is not supported

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I created a new Eclipse plugin with an empty target definition where I added a local eclipse installation as a repository, because I want to have a light minimal product.

The content of the target file is:

```
<target name="clean_target" sequenceNumber="16">
    <locations>
        <location path="D:\eclipse" type="Profile"/>
    </locations>
</target>
```

When I try to build the product with `Maven Tycho` I get the following warning:
`[WARNING] Target location type 'Profile' is not supported`.

What does that mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Would be good to share the related code as well as the command(s) how to build and use it. Explain better what you mean: _I created a new plugin_, is it a Maven plugin, Eclipse plugin, or even some other product plugin ?

Comment: @Verhagen Updated